# Filter list inside the list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a following list of objects:

```
List<Parent> parents = new();
```

Parent contains `List<Children>` list of children.

What I want is to filter list of parents and return female children for all parents. (and ignore/remove male children)

```
List<Parent> parentsAndTheirFemales = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Gender == "female")).ToList();
```

I tried it with the above approach, but apparently it does not do the filtering.

I know I could remap it to DTO but let's consider that I have far too many properties on my parent class and I don't want to do that.

Is there another option?

EDIT: I settled with remapping.

```
parents.Select(FilterFemales());

static Func<Parent, Parent> FilterFemales()
        {
            return parent => new Parent()
            {
                Name = parent.Name,
                ... all properties
                Children = parent.Children.Where(c => c.Gender == "female").ToList()
            };
        }
```

Comment: Another option to what? You told us what you want to do and you're doing it. What's the problem you're trying to solve? What do you want that you don't have?

Comment: Are you saying that you actually want to remove the items that don't match your criteria from the existing list?

Comment: That's right, Any() does not work as it returns true if condition is satisfied for at least one item.

Comment: for parents with ONLY daughters - use All instead of Any.

Comment: All does not work as it ignores all children if at least one is not female.
I need to somehow filter the female children and return them.

Sorry, I was not precise enough, the key is that I want children filtered.

Comment: Why don't you iterate the parents and remove all non-female children from their children lists instead of fiddling around with linq? If you do not want to mutate the original list, you need to make a deep copy, first, of course.

Comment: I think I'll settle with that.

Comment: I'm still not clear. Are you trying to return a list of parents that have girls (including all their children), a list of parents but with only the girls included or a list of just the girls?

Comment: List of parents with only girls included, ignore boys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to return all parents that have girls, but only the girls included (hence the "Filter inside the list of objects" title) you can do this:

```
 var parentsWithTheirGirls = data.Where(parent => parent.Children.Any(child => child.Gender == "Female"))
                                 .Select(p => new Parent 
                                 { 
                                     Name = p.Name, 
                                     Children = GetChildren(p.Children, "Female") 
                                 }).ToList();
```

'GetChildren' is just another method to do the filtering like this:

```
static List<Child> GetChildren(IEnumerable<Child> children, string gender)
{
    return children.Where(child => child.Gender == gender).ToList();
}
```

You don't need to have the child filter in a separate method but I think it makes it more readable. I would also use an enum for the gender in place of a string.

Comment: Yes, that was the only way, I wanted to check if there is some other, but I settled with that.

Comment: It's not the only way. Does the Child have a link back to the parent, such as a parentId?

Comment: it does not have any links to the parent

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution would be to extend your `Parent` class with a method that takes a predicate for the `Children` property. Perhaps do you at some point want to return parents with only the *male* children, without having to reimplement too much logic?

Example implementation:

```csharp
public class Parent
{
    // Other properties
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    
    public Parent CopyWithChildFilter(Func<Child, bool> childPredicate)
    {
        return new() 
        { 
            // Set other properties
            Children = Children.Where(childPredicate).ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```csharp
List<Parent> parents = new();

Func<Child, bool> isFemaleChild = c => c.Gender == "female";
//Func<Child, bool> isMaleChild = c => c.Gender == "male";

List<Parent> parentsAndTheirFemales = parents
    .Where(p => p.Children.Any(isFemaleChild))
    .Select(p => p.CopyWithChildFilter(isFemaleChild))
    .ToList();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iSCsc0).

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing an equal sign in Gender = "Female"?

```
List<Parent> parentsAndTheirFemales = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Gender = "female")).ToList();
```

should be

```
List<Parent> parentsAndTheirFemales = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Gender == "female")).ToList();
```

or even better to avoid it use the .Equals function

Comment: I was typing quickly, take my example as a reference only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `SelectMany` is what you're looking for?

```
parentsAndTheirFemales.SelectMany(
    c => c.Children.Where(c => c.Gender == "female")
);
```

Comment: That will return a flattened `IEnumerable<Child>`.

Comment: That's right, I managed to do it with remapping the whole parent object and then filtering children with where, but I wondered if there is some c# magic that will do it.

Comment: Yes as expected, wasn't that the question? Maybe I misunderstood :)

Comment: I want to return the list of parents with their female children, if they have ones, and ignore the ones with male children.

Comment: Ah right,
then sr28 answer is great I guess if you want to remap using linq instead of static method.
            
Or in another style:
`var query = from Parent p in parents
                        where p.Children.Any(p => p.Gender == "F")
                        select new Parent()
                        {
                            Children = p.Children.Where(p => p.Gender == "F").ToList()
                        };`
Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for;

```
 var girls = parents
      SelectMany(family => 
      family.Childs.Where(child => child.Gender == "Female"), 
      (parent, daughter) => new { parent = parent.Name, daughter = daughter.Name });
```

Have a look my small test:

```
public class Parent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }



var parents = new List<Parent>()
        {
            new Parent
            {
                Name = "Anderson",
                Childs = new List<Child>
                {
                    new Child
                    {
                        Name = "Alex",
                        Gender = "Male"
                    },
                    new Child
                    {
                        Name = "Maria",
                        Gender = "Female"
                    },
                    new Child
                    {
                        Name = "Sabrina",
                        Gender = "Female"
                    }

                }
            },
             new Parent
            {
                Name = "Clark",
                Childs = new List<Child>
                {
                    new Child
                    {
                        Name = "Mario",
                        Gender = "Male"
                    },
                    new Child
                    {
                        Name = "Marina",
                        Gender = "Female"
                    }

                }
            }

        };

          var girls = parents
      SelectMany(family => 
      family.Childs.Where(child => child.Gender == "Female"), 
      (parent, daughter) => new { parent = parent.Name, daughter = daughter.Name });
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in girls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

And this the result :

> { parent = Anderson, daughter = Maria }
>
> { parent = Clark, daughter = Marina }
>
> { parent = Clark, daughter = Sabrina }

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = parents;
foreach (var p in filtered)
{
    p.Children.RemoveAll(c => c.Gender == "Male");
}
filtered.RemoveAll(p => !p.Children.Any());
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.